# CSV upload Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2, highcharts

I have a rails project that I need to upload a csv file and generate a graph, but I am unsure on how best to approach this.

**I am able to upload the csv file using paperclip and store in my database.**

I using the gems lazy_high_chartsand gmaps4rails and I can map to a town with my Latitude and Longitude coordinates just fine, but I would also like in the display of each marker to display a highcharts graph from a csv that I want to store in a directory and output to the relevant town.

My form

```
<%= simple_form_for @soiltemp, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :site %>
    <%= f.input :latitude %>
    <%= f.input :longitude %>
    <%= f.input :csv, as: :file %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Index View

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<h1>Soil Temperatures</h1>
<hr>

<div style='width: 100%;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 500px;'></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class SoiltempsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @soiltemps = Soiltemp.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@soiltemps) do |soiltemps, marker|
      marker.lat soiltemps.latitude
      marker.lng soiltemps.longitude
      marker.infowindow soiltemps.want to display graph here
    end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "soiltemps", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "site"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "csv"
  end
```

Comment: Is the question how to upload a csv file or how to use it to generate the graph? or both?

Comment: Thanks for answering diego, both uploading and grabbing the data (specific columns) from the csv file then generating the graph.

Comment: Have you tried the gem Paperclip for uploading files? Assuming you already have CSV files that you want to upload.

Comment: Good point. Integrating it now. Thanks.

Comment: Worked. I am able to save the csv file to my database using paperclip.

Comment: Cool, then you can use the ruby standard CSV library to read the file and parse it into something you can work with to render to highcharts.